# How do I write "If a AND b is true then load x"

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to write a simple condition that states if a AND b are true then add x ElseIf... a AND c are true then add x ElseIf just do this. (I really hope that makes as much sense in writing as it does in my head.

The current code is:

```
if($layout == "carousel") {
    $document->addStyleSheet($modbase.'css/stylev1.css');
    $document->addScript($modbase.'js/jqueryv1.js');
}
```

Basically I want it to do this...

```
if($layout == "carousel" AND BODyID IS B) {
    $document->addStyleSheet($modbase.'css/stylev1.css');
    $document->addScript($modbase.'js/jqueryv1.js');
}
Else if ($layout == "carousel" AND BODYID IS C) {
    $document->addStyleSheet($modbase.'css/stylev2.css');
    $document->addScript($modbase.'js/jqueryv2.js');
}
```

But as you can see I'm not entirely sure what the exact code would look like.

Comment: @JamesGoodwin The BODYID is the Body Id of the webpage set in the HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write out your sentence in code and you are golden!

```
if ($layout == "carousel" && $bodyid == $b)
{
    $document->addStyleSheet($modbase.'css/stylev1.css');
    $document->addScript($modbase.'js/jqueryv1.js');

}
else if($layout == "carousel" && $bodyid == $c)
{
    $document->addStyleSheet($modbase.'css/stylev2.css');
    $document->addScript($modbase.'js/jqueryv2.js');
}
else 
{
    // Just do this
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the construct you're looking for:

```
if ($layout == "carousel" && $bodyId == B) {
    // Code
} elseif ($layout == "carousel" && $bodyId == C) {
    // Code
}
```

Only if both conditions are `true` the result is `true`. This is basic [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra). There are also operators for `either one must be true` which is `||` and so forth.

If you're struggling with the very basic syntax I recommend reading a good book or some online resource. Invest some hours, they will pay off very soon!

Comment: I'll give that a try just now, hopefully that will do the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($layout == "carousel") {
    if(BODyID == B) {
        $document->addStyleSheet($modbase.'css/stylev1.css');
        $document->addScript($modbase.'js/jqueryv1.js');
    } elseif (BODYID == C) {
        $document->addStyleSheet($modbase.'css/stylev2.css');
        $document->addScript($modbase.'js/jqueryv2.js');
    }
}
```

Deluxe version:

```
// Assuming that BODYID, B and C are constants and BODyID is a typo.
if ($layout == 'carousel') {

    switch(BODYID) {
        case B:
            $stylesheet = $modbase.'css/stylev1.css';
            $script     = $modbase.'js/jqueryv1.js';
        break;

        case C:
        default:
            $stylesheet = $modbase.'css/stylev2.css';
            $script     = $modbase.'js/jqueryv2.js';
    }

    $document->addStyleSheet($stylesheet);
    $document->addScript($script);
}
```

Short version:

```
if ($layout == 'carousel') {
    $stylesheet = BODYID == B ? 'css/stylev1.css' : 'css/stylev2.css';
    $script     = BODYID == B ? 'js/jqueryv1.js'  : 'js/jqueryv2.js';

    $document->addStyleSheet($modbase.$stylesheet);
    $document->addScript($modbase.$script);
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out you only need to evaluate `$layout == "carousel"` once.

Comment: @TMN - While I agree this is the most efficient way... this might lead to ugly nesting of code.

Comment: @afuzzyllama, I added a deluxe version which prevents ugly nested if/else code.

Comment: @afuzzyllama is totally right, the "deluxe" version is way harder to read. And for what? One comparison less than before... not a good deal IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Give && a try.

```
if(a == b && c == y)
{
    //do something
}
else if(a == b && c == x)
{
    //do something else
}
```